# Swift - Add attributed string to items in parenthesis

Tags: regex, swift, string

I'm trying to display text to a view from a set of definitions and in cases where that text/string has parenthesis, I would like to display that parenthesis element in a different way - let's say bolded vs non bolded.

> "**This string a**"
>
> "**This string b** (has parenthesis)" - parenthesis show in lower
>   weight font

Now I'm aware that the solution is found by combining regular expressions - `\(\w*\)` - with attributed strings, but I haven't been able to combine it meaningfully.

This is my function that prints the words

```
func setWord(_ index:Int) {
    if (index < 0) { return }
    let word:[String:AnyObject] = self.definitions[index]
    if let wordLabelText = word[self.store.sourceLanguage.lowercased()] as? String {
        self.wordLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wordLabelText, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0])
    }
    print(word)
    self.definitionView.word = word
}
```

What I've done so far is added some more definitions for the attributed strings output, but then I'm not sure how to continue:

```
func setWord(_ index:Int) {
    if (index < 0) { return }
    let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
    let fontSize = font.pointSize * 3
    let plainFont = UIFont(name: "X-BoldItalic", size: fontSize)
    let boldFont = UIFont(name: "X-Italic", size: fontSize)
    let word:[String:AnyObject] = self.definitions[index]
    if let wordLabelText = word[self.store.sourceLanguage.lowercased()] as? String {
        self.wordLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wordLabelText, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSFontAttributeName: boldFont])
```

Here I'd need to loop through the words looking for the (elements), but I'm not sure how to do that and properly return the words. Am I on the right path? Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in Objective-C, with explained logic that should be easily translated in Swift.

```
NSDictionary *defaultAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]};
NSDictionary *otherAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]};

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(.*?\\)" options:0 error:nil];
NSString *initialString = @"This string a (has parenthesis), This string b (has parenthesis too), This string C hasn't.";

NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:initialString attributes:defaultAttributes];
NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);
NSArray *allMatches = [regex matchesInString:[attr string] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attr length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *aResult in allMatches)
{
    [attr addAttributes:otherAttributes range:[aResult range]];
}
NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);
```

Logs:

```
$> Attr: This string a (has parenthesis), This string b (has parenthesis too), This string C hasn't.{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14663df0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Semibold\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}
$> Attr: This string a {
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14663df0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Semibold\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}(has parenthesis){
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14666260> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
}, This string b {
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14663df0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Semibold\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}(has parenthesis too){
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14666260> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
}, This string C hasn't.{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x14663df0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Semibold\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}
```

What is the idea:
Create a `NSMutableAttributedString` with the "default" attributes (in our case bold font with "big size").
Then create a `NSRegularExpression` and find all occurrences.
You'll add the attributes (in our case small and normal font) at that occurrence range.

In our case, it works simply, because since you can only have one attribute per kind maximum at a specific range, the `NSFontAttributeName` attribute will be replaced for that range.

If you added more attributes, and want to remove them, you may need to not call `addAttributes:range:`, but `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:` instead:

```
NSAttributedString *replacement = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[[attr string] substringWithRange:[aResult range]]
                                                                  attributes:otherAttributes];
[attr replaceCharactersInRange:[aResult range] withAttributedString:replacement];
```

**Edit:** Swift 3 Version

**Nota Bene:** I'm clearly not a Swift Developer, this code seems to work, but clearly, I "write" Swift like I write Objective-C, and many things since I don't use them daily and didn't read the doc are wrongly done (like the conversion/cast/explicit type/class, the "as", the "!", the "?", etc.), but it could be a start for you.
If you are a Swift developer and spots issues, feel free to comment the post and suggest your modifications. If you're just here because you have the same issue, don't forget to read in the comment if there are more Swifty things to fix in my pseudo code.

```
let defaultAttributes:[String:Any] = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:15)];
let otherAttributes:[String:Any] = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:12)];


do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "\\(.*?\\)", options: [])
    let initialString:String = "This string a (has parenthesis), This string b (has parenthesis too), This string C hasn't."
    let attr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: initialString, attributes: defaultAttributes)
    print("Attr\(attr)");
    let allMatches:[NSTextCheckingResult] = regex.matches(in: attr.string, options:[], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attr.string.characters.count))
    for aResult in allMatches
    {
        let occurrence = (attr.string as NSString).substring(with: aResult.range)
        let replacement = NSAttributedString.init(string: occurrence , attributes: otherAttributes)
        attr.replaceCharacters(in: aResult.range, with: replacement)
    //attr.addAttributes(otherAttributes, range: aResult.range)
    }
    print("Attr\(attr)");
} catch let regexError {
    print(regexError)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your time! I've been able to follow along, convert to Swift, but still struggling getting all of the errors ironed out. I'll check it out again and again during the next days and see if I get it to work.

Comment: @Simon I wrote a pseudo code in Swift (it compiles and works) with I'm sure some errors/bad habits, but it may give you a better idea.

Comment: super greatful and trying to get it working every free minute available. It's just me being super new to iOS and actual coding in general, so it takes some banging the head against the wall sometimes.